Reality check: error in Lakshmibai and Raghavan's book on standard monomials?
This is a reality-check question that is very in the weeds of a specific print source. I am confounded by the following point in Lakshmibai and Raghavan's book Standard Monomial Theory: Invariant Theoretic Approach. (Here is the Google Books link, but I am actually accessing it through my university library's website.) It is in Ch. 12, which is on the invariant ring of $SO(n,K)$ (where $K$ is an algebraically closed field of odd characteristic), acting diagonally on $m$ copies of $K^n$.
Let $u=(u_1,\dots,u_m)$ be an $m$-tuple of vectors each lying in $K^n$. (The authors think of $u$ as an $m\times n$ matrix whose rows are the $u_j$, so $SO(n,K)$ is acting from the right, but I don't think this matters for what follows.) Let $X$ be the vector space of all such $u$. Let $U$ be the gram matrix of the $u_j$'s, i.e., $U=(\langle u_i,u_j\rangle)_{ij}$, where $\langle,\rangle$ is the standard dot product; it is an $m\times m$ symmetric matrix.
If $A$ and $B$ are both $k$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,m\}$ with $k\leq \min(m,n)$, then define $p(A,B)$ to be the determinant of the $k\times k$ minor of the symmetric matrix $U$ whose row indices are given by $A$ and whose column indices are given by $B$. It is a regular function on $X$ that is invariant under the $O(n,K)$-action and therefore the $SO(n,K)$-action.
Assuming $m\geq n$, if $I=\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$ is an $n$-subset of $\{1,\dots,m\}$, then define $u(I)$ to be the determinant $\det(u_{i_1},\dots,u_{i_n})$. It is a regular function on $X$ that is invariant under the $SL(n,K)$ and therefore the $SO(n,K)$-action.
These definitions are made at the beginning of Sec. 12.2 of the book, on p. 167. Immediately next, Lemma 12.2.0.1 notes the identity $u(I)u(J) = p(I,J)$ if $I$ and $J$ are both $n$-subsets of $1,\dots,m$.
The thing that confounds me is what happens after that. Definition 12.2.1.1 defines a monomial
$$ p(A_1,B_1)\dots p(A_r,B_r)u(I_1)\dots u(I_s)$$
in the $p$'s and $u$'s as standard if $A_1\geq B_1\geq A_2\geq B_2 \geq \dots\geq B_r \geq I_1\geq \dots\geq I_s$ with respect to a certain partial order (namely $A\geq B$ means that if the numbers in $A$ are arranged in a column from least to greatest, and same for $B$, then $A$ could be placed to the right of $B$ in a semi-standard Young tableaux). This definition does not place any restriction on $s$.
Then, Section 12.2.2, in particular Proposition 12.2.2.2, claims that the standard monomials are linearly independent.
This is what confounds me. Take $n$-subsets $I,J\subset\{1,\dots,m\}$ with $I\geq J$. Then aren't $p(I,J)$ and $u(I)u(J)$ both standard monomials? But then doesn't the relation $p(I,J)=u(I)u(J)$ given by Lemma 12.2.0.1 immediately contradict the claim that they are linearly independent?
I am further confounded because the proof of Proposition 12.2.2.2 repeatedly uses Lemma 12.2.0.1. It seems to me that what the argument is really proving is that if $s$ is restricted to $\{0,1\}$ then we get a linearly independent set of monomials.
Am I fundamentally misreading the book? What am I missing?

The text at the start of section 12.2.1 defines the index sets $H_u$ and $H_p$ used to restrict possible $A_k$, $B_k$, $I_k$ in the definition of the standard monomial. In particular, the definition of $H_p$ says that in the standard monomial we only take $p(A_k, B_k)$ with $A_k$ and $B_k$ of size at most $n - 1$. The identity $u(I)u(J) = p(I, J)$ uses sets of size $n$, so in this case $p(I, J)$ will not be standard.

Thank you! This is a relief. That said, don't you think the proof of Prop 12.2.2.2 is written in a manner that is inconsistent with this convention? In particular, the $P_i$ that are obtained in the course of the proof are not standard with respect to this convention, right? (Although they are standard in the sense needed for the call to Theorem 12.1.7.2 to go through.)

Yes, you are right, the naming is inconsistent there. I guess it's still technically a standard monomial if we expand all $p$ with sets of size $n$. Maybe it's better to think about two representations of a standard monomial, one with $p(A, B)$ with index sets of size at most $n - 1$, and another with at most one $u(I)$.
